# Правильно ли я поставил запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

> БГ+ приготовили уникальное, теплое, шоу связывающее «аквариумные»
> времена и современность!

Все ли правильно? Смущает запятая после слова «теплое».

Comment: Не нужна запятая, а то вы обособите определения от существительного. Поставьте запятую после "шоу", обособив причастный оборот.

Comment: не понятно, что вы хотите сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так (с запятой **после** слова "шоу"):
*БГ+ приготовили уникальное, теплое **шоу,** связывающее «аквариумные» времена и современность!*

Правило:
если причастный оборот [*связывающее «аквариумные» времена и современность*] находится после определяемого слова [*шоу*], то он обособляется запятыми.

*— В эфире — «Все тайны русского мира», первое интерактивное **шоу, связывающее два мира, наш и загробный,** и я, его ведущий Иван Корифейчик* (Анна и Сергей Литвиновы. Мертвые не лгут).

[Пунктуация при причастном обороте](https://lc.rt.ru/classbook/oge-russkii-yazyk-9-klass/sintaksis-i-punktuatsiya-77/1513)